# Redirect open link event to extendedwebbrowser tab

Tags: c#, winforms, events, browser

I've got a webbrowser in a c# form and when the user click on a link the page opens in the ie10 browser.

All I want is to intercept this event and open the new page in another webbrowser (extendendwebbrowser really).

The fact is that i don't want to know what the user click in the page, but i'd like to intercept all the requests "open new page" from my webbrowser and redirect them to  my extendedwebbrowserform and create a new tab with that link.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 ways to do that:

1. Extend the WebBrowser control to intercept the NewWindow2 event, then cancel original request and use that url to open it in a new window. Similar code can be found [here](http://blogs.artinsoft.net/Mrojas/archive/2008/09/18/Extended-WebBrowser-Control-SeriesNewWindow2-Events-in-the-C-WebBrowserControl.aspx) or in code project [Extended .NET 2.0 WebBrowser Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13598/Extended-NET-2-0-WebBrowser-Control).
2. Implement INewWindowManager, and use EvaluateNewWindow to do the same.